# Linux Mint not recognising free space created by Windows 10 shrink

Tags: linux-mint, partition, windows, dual-boot

I have Windows 10 installed on my HP laptop, and since I'm starting to do some programming, I decided I'd like to get Linux on it too by creating a partition.

I used the Windows tool to shrink C down and create 50GB of unallocated space (attached).

I downloaded Linux Mint onto a USB and booted it up, tried to install it using what I expected to find on "free space" of the unallocated portion, but it's not there! I couldn't find any free space; all I get is:

```
/dev/sda1      Size: 1MB       Used: unknown    System: Windows 10 Loader
/dev/sda2 ntfs Size: 208MB     Used: unknown    System: Windows Recovery Environment (loader)
/dev/sda3 ntfs Size: 682780MB  Used: 12997MB    System: Windows Recovery Environment (loader)
/dev/sda4      Size: 67165MB   Used: unknown
```

I can't even see how the volumes tie up together!

[image: Windows Shrink tool]

Comment: Similar unanswered questions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283058/linux-mint-17-3-installer-claiming-that-drive-doesnt-have-enough-space?rq=1) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/457721/edit)

Answer (score 2):

i'm pretty sure the shrinking with windows caused your problems! at least since then your drive was converted to a *"[Dynamic Disk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx)"* (as you can see on your screenshot).

a long story made short: *Dynamic Disks* are a *"microsoft-invention"* to overcome some limitations of [msdos-MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) (and make interaction with other OSes more complicated)...

---

the **solution** is to revert the changes (delete the new partition, etc.) and [**convert back to a *Basic Disk***](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755238.aspx). and then modify your partitions with your live-system (of course after a backup!) right before installing.
at the moment i have no time (and setups) to test and post a full tutorial, but i'm sure asking your trusted search will give you enough results...

---

this topic was also mentioned at the Linux Mint forum: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=116723

the **conclusion** for the future: *everything you can achieve without windows, do without windows!* because windows strictly ignores other systems, setups and so on... the easiest example is the setup: windows wipes all other OSes without a hassle...

Comment: just to mention it... there is a library to handle "Dynamic Disks": https://github.com/mdbooth/libldm

Answer (score -1):

First , you should make the unallocated space ntfs. After this boot up linux mint and install it in your ntfs 50gb partition. It will format it from ntfs to ext4

Comment: Thanks, I tried this however the only difference is when I try to install Linux again, it changes the following drives:                                            /dev/sda3 ntfs Size: 682780MB Used: 100MB System: (blank)
/dev/sda4 ntfs Size: 67165MB  Used: 12997MB Windows Recovery Environment (loader)